# Easy way to set conditional uniqueness to django model

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-forms, unique

In the model below, while ham is same value, each spam need to be uniqu.

```
class MyModel(models.model):
    ham = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    spam = models.CarField(max_length=200)
```

I understand it's probably possible to validate them on form but just wonder if there is an easy way to do it on model.

Comment: `spam = models.CarField(max_length=200, unique=True)`

Answer (score 0):

If you need `ham` and `spam` values must be unique together, use [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together) option:

```
class MyModel(models.model):
    ham = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    spam = models.CarField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("ham", "spam"),)
```